# Unable to rdp into Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have spun up a micro instance of windows 2008 r2 server with sql server and iis installed.
My security group has three inbound rules:
rdp tcp: 3389 0.0.0.0/0
mssql tcp:1433  0.0.0.0/0
http tcp:80 0.0.0.0/0

outbound is all traffic 0.0.0.0/0

I can rdp into other instances which are on a private cloud which is openstack in my college.

I followed the instructions, de-crypt the password after downloading the pem file. I get an error saying i cannot connect. I used this website: http://www.mynetworktest.com/ports.php to check if the 3389 port was open on my ec2 instance; it says it is not. I tried changing security groups but does not make a difference. The only discrepancy i could determine is when i set up the instance. I have to set 'Auto Assign Public IP' to enable in order to get a public ip address; something which the amazon docs does not clarify.

Am out of ideas, Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me and this is how I resolved it.

It is likely your windows firewall is restricting incoming RDP traffic. First disable windows firewall totally. If you are able to connect after disabling the firewall, then firewall rules are the issue. Enable firewall and edit firewall rules to allow incoming RDP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

for windows and linux servers check for 2 things to make the remote or ssh working

- check for the firewall/iptables
- check for the security groups or ports open to what destination.
- check for the services and user groups open for communication
- check the service.

Comment: checked everything,  difference; unless i'm missing something.